# Object reference not set to an instance of an object app.config

Tags: c#, xml

This is my app.config that I added at the root of my project(type:ClassLibrary) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="POS_DEV_GIL-001" connectionString="Server=FACOX\SQLEXPRESSPOS;Database=POS_DEV_GIL-001;Trusted_Connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I added as reference the System.Configuration.dll

In my code, I do that :

```
using System.configuration;
//rest of the code
String connec = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POS_DEV_GIL-001"].ConnectionString;
```

And I get the following error :

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Have you also got an `app.config` or `web.config` in the project that is consuming this class library?

Comment: Have you debugged to see what specifically is null (Thats the cause of that error)

Comment: It doesn't exist web.config in my project. I've just created a App.config xml file at the root of my project.

Comment: This is a class library right?  What application are you running the code from?  Have you put the connection string in there?

Comment: You must be sure to add this connection string to the executable's config file rather to your library one.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned the project is a Class Library.  Meaning on compile it is not an executable, but a DLL.  Class libraries will, by default, look to the application that executes it for its config files.  What application are you running that uses the class library? Make sure the application that uses this library has an `app.config` or a `web.config` with the connection string:

```
<add name="POS_DEV_GIL-001" connectionString="Server=FACOX\SQLEXPRESSPOS;Database=POS_DEV_GIL-001;Trusted_Connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: A very good catch indeed, It must be helpful for future users. +1. I have seen/experienced similar issue with having WCF services and configuration in separate project and then try to use the same configuration in the application project.